# yum install error Centos 5

Tags: python, centos, yum

I cannot find any information regarding the issue I am having so here it is.
While trying to yum install php-pear (infact running yum at all) I run into this problem:

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

```
cannot import name canCoinstall

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Nov 11 2010, 13:34:43) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

And as it says above - something to do with the module canCoinstall.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: maybe this: http://www.matteomattei.com/en/install-yum-and-php-pear-on-centos-5/
can help you.

Comment: Uninstall your yum and reinstall it to match your version of Centos and Python.

Answer (score 2):

change your python version in yum to lower, 
such as：/etc/bin/yum

change

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
```